# Image link cant be extracted from scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract image link of a product from  [www.flipkart.com](https://www.flipkart.com) website but the output returned is an empty list I tried all the combinations please help
'''

```
class StackSpider(Spider):
   name = "stack"
   allowed_domains = ["flipkart.com"]
   start_urls = [
    "https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen",
]
   def parse(self, response):
    
     image_url = response.css('._2r_T1I::attr(src)').extract()
     item['image_url'] = image_url
     yield item
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be something about websites policy.
Below code works really fine for this website

```
url = "http://hdresim.net/"
source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
main = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":'icerik'})
for i in main.findAll("img"):
  print(i["src"])
```

Results like:

```
http://hdresim.net/resimler/r6/k_karinca(10).jpg
http://hdresim.net/resimler/r3/k_deniz_canlilari(38).jpg
http://hdresim.net/resimler/r5/k_sonbahar14(44).jpg
http://hdresim.net/resimler/r7/k_yaz16(3).jpg
..
```

But when i try same approach to your site i will get empty list

```
url = "https://www.flipkart.com/clothing-and-accessories/topwear/pr?sid=clo%2Cash&otracker=categorytree&p%5B%5D=facets.ideal_for%255B%255D%3DMen"
source = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

main = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class":"_13oc-S"})

for images in  soup.findAll("img", attrs={"class":"_2r_T1I"}):
  print(images["src"])
```